# Convex Polygon Intersection

Tags: computational-geometry, convex-optimization, geometry, constraints

Determining the intersection of two convex polygons is one of the fundamental problems in computational geometry .
I'm asking for an algorithm having:

## INPUT:

Given two convex polygons P and Q in 2D (note that the two convex polygons are represented with p & q points)

## OUTPUT :

compute their intersection?

Can any one help me !!!

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An algorithm for this computation is described in *[Computational Geometry in C](http://cs.smith.edu/~orourke/books/compgeom.html)*, Chapter 7, Section 6. Code is available at that link. Much of the tricky code is concerned with "degenerate" cases.

Here is a nice Univ Montreal web page (Eric Plante) that describes a different algorithm:
[link](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~plante/compGeom/algorithm.html).

---

[image: Plante fig]

---